# Avoid quotation marks in column and row names when using write.table

Tags: r, double-quotes, write.table

I have the following data in a file called "data.txt":

```
pid      1     2     4     15      18       20
1_at   100   200   89    189     299      788
2_at     8    78   33     89      90       99
3_xt   300    45   53    234      89       34
4_dx    49    34   88      8       9       15
```

The data is separated by tabs.

Now I wanted to extract some columns on that table, based on the information of csv file called "vector.csv", this vector got the following data:

```
18,1,4,20
```

So I wanted to end with a modified file "datamod.txt" separated with tabs that would be:

```
pid      18       1     4      20
1_at   299     100    89     788
2_at    90       8    33      99
3_xt    89     300    53      34
4_dx     9      49    88      15
```

I have made, with some help, the following code:

```
fileName="vector.csv"
con=file(fileName,open="r")
controlfile<-readLines(con)
controls<-controlfile[1]
controlins<-controlfile[2]
test<-paste("pid",controlins,sep=",")
test2<-c(strsplit(test,","))
test3<-c(do.call("rbind",test2)) 
df<-read.table("data.txt",header=T,check.names=F)
CC <- sapply(df, class)
CC[!names(CC) %in% test3] <- "NULL"
df <- read.table("data.txt", header=T, colClasses=CC,check.names=F)
df<-df[,test3]
write.table(df,"datamod.txt",row.names=FALSE,sep="\t")
```

The problem that I got is that my resulting file has the following format:

```
"pid"      "18"       "1"     "4"      "20"
"1_at"   299         100      89       788
"2_at"    90           8      33        99
"3_xt"    89         300      53        34
"4_dx"     9          49      88        15
```

The question I have is how to avoid those quotation "" marks that appear in my saved file, so that the data appears like I would like to.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `quote` argument to `write.table` set it too `FALSE`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To *quote* from the help file for `write.table`

`quote`

> a logical value (TRUE or FALSE) or a numeric vector. If TRUE,
>   any character or factor columns will be surrounded by double quotes.
>   If a numeric vector, its elements are taken as the indices of columns
>   to quote. In both cases, row and column names are quoted if they are
>   written. If FALSE, nothing is quoted.

Therefore

```
write.table(df,"datamod.txt",row.names=FALSE,sep="\t", quote = FALSE)
```

should work nicely.