# R - How to remove double quotes (" ") in the string values of write.table(... .txt) output?

Tags: r, write.table

Suppose I have the following dataset, dat:

```
     Name   Account No. Occupation
     Marie  7672        Nurse
     Jerry  0986        Veterinarian
     Max    3927        Hairdresser
```

I output a dataset, named "dat" using the following codes:

```
write.table(dat, file = paste(date, 'output.txt'), na ="", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE, sep = '\t')
```

`output.txt` looks like

```
     "Name"     "Account No."    "Occupation"
     "Marie"    7672    "Nurse"
     "Jerry"    0986    "Veterinarian"
     "Max"    3927    "Hairdresser"
```

How do I remove the double quotes in the final output?

Comment: I believe it would be useful for you to check out function gsub: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid quotation marks in column and row names when using write.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846433/avoid-quotation-marks-in-column-and-row-names-when-using-write-table)

Comment: `quote = FALSE` removes quoting. Read `?write.table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
write.table(dat, file=paste(date, 'output.txt'), na ="", row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, sep='\t', quote=FALSE)
```

You can use the `quote` parameter.